# Creating DataFrame from XML document

Tags: python, xml, pandas, elementtree

I understand this question has been asked a few times but I've tried everything to no avail. I'm not sure if this is an edge case or I'm missing something. I'm trying to parse an xml file and return as a df. Below is my attempt:

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
import pandas as pd
from lxml import objectify
tree = ET.parse('file.xml')
root = tree.getroot()

  <?xml version="1.0"?>
 -<document page-count="1">
    -<page number="1">
       -<table data-table="1" data-page="1" data-filename="Schedule.pdf">
           -<tr>
                <td colspan="17">Wednesday 20th Mar</td>
           -</tr>
           -<tr>
                <td colspan="3" style="text-align: right">1</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">2</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">3</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">4</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">5</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">6</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">7</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">8</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">9</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">10</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">11</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">12</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">13</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">14</td>
                <td style="text-align: right">15</td>
            </tr>
           -<tr>
                <td>HOME</td>
                <td>D</td>
                <td/>
                <td/>
                <td>08:00</td>
                <td>09:00</td>
                <td>10:00</td>
                <td>11:00</td>
                <td>12:00</td>
                <td>13:00</td>
                <td/>
                <td/>
                <td/>
                <td colspan="4"/>
            </tr>            
        </table>
     </page>
  </document>
```

I can export the data as strings:

```
print(ET.tostring(root, encoding='utf8').decode('utf8'))
```

But when trying to export as a df it returns an empty frame:

```
xml = objectify.parse('file.xml')
root = xml.getroot()

data=[]
for i in range(len(root.getchildren())):
    data.append([child.text for child in root.getchildren()[i].getchildren()])

df = pd.DataFrame(data).T
```

Out:

```
      0
0  None
```

If the date is stripped I'm hoping to Intended Output will be:

```
         1      2      3      4      5      6      7      8 9 10 11 12 13 14 15
0  HOME  D      08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00
```

Comment: What programming language?

Comment: @jdweng Python.

Comment: The xml posted is not complete.  It is missing end tags for table, page and document.  See : https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't have Pandas right now, but I think you can try this code to get your `data`

```
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xml = ET.parse('file.xml')

root = xml.getroot()

data = []
for child in root.iter('td'):
    data.append(child.text)
```

Answer (score 2):

In the example XML,  element in first table row 10 is not closed. If fixed, you can simply do (provided your file.xml is read to string `a`):

```
>>> pd.read_html(a, header=1)[0]
      1 1.1  1.2   2      3      4      5      6      7      8   9  10  11  12  13  14  15
0  HOME   D  NaN NaN  08:00  09:00  10:00  11:00  12:00  13:00 NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

It looks like in your expected output, you shifted data row 1 position to the right.